# There is no overloaded version of 'SendMsg' that can be called with these arguments

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am in the process of upgrading a project from Delphi 2006 to Delphi XE2 and have come across the compile error **There is no overloaded version of 'SendMsg' that can be called with these arguments.**
This is the code where the problem is.

```
procedure TMessageComms.UpgradeError(Msg: String);
begin
  FConnection.SendMsg(cUpgradeError, Msg, FConnection.GetNextMsgID);
end;
```

The SendMsg method looks like this.

```
procedure SendMsg(ACommand, AParamStr : String; AMsgID : Integer); overload;

procedure TMsgConnection.SendMsg(ACommand, AParamStr: String; AMsgID: Integer);
begin
  // construct message
  // send message
end;
```

cUpgradeError is a const declared like so.

```
 cUpgradeError = 'UpgradeError';
```

And this is the GetNextMsgID function that returns an Integer.

```
function TMsgConnection.GetNextMsgID: Integer;
begin
  Inc(FLastMsgID);
  Result := FLastMsgID;
end;
```

The parameters all seem valid to me.
I have managed to narrow it down to the point where it's something to do with the GetNextMsgID function but unsure what. If I cast the value returned from the function to an Integer then it compiles fine, but I can't see why I should have to.

Comment: Well I don't think it's the `GetNextMsgID` function, since I don't know what you mean exactly about "Cast as integer" since the code you provided is already all Integer values.

Comment: Can you provide the types of the values passed in this procedure? I mean `cUpgradeError` should be of type `String`, same as `Msg` (which I see it is), and `FConnection.GetNextMsgID` as you post above is already an integer.

Comment: Exactly, I'm also confused. If I change the code to `FConnection.SendMsg(cUpgradeError, Msg, Integer(FConnection.GetNextMsgID));` it compiles.

Comment: So althouth `GetNextMsgID` returns an integer, `SendMsg` is expecting you to cast it as `Integer()`?

Comment: Are there any overloaded versions of `GetNextMsgID` or `SendMsg` at all?

Comment: Correct, and I have no idea why. Worked fine in Delphi 2006.

Comment: Now that is puzzling, if you have overloads the problem may be there, but if not, I am scratching my head with a toothpick...

Comment: `SendMsg()` is declared as `overload`, which does suggests there are other versions of `SendMsg()` floating around. But the only way casting the return value of `GetNextMsgID()` would make the code work is if `GetNextMsgID()` is not actually declared to return an `Integer`.

Comment: My guess is that `FConnection.SendMsg(cUpgradeError, Msg, FConnection.GetNextMsgID);` is trying to interpret `FConnection.GetNextMsgID` as a function pointer instead of a function result. Just for grins, try changing it to `FConnection.SendMsg(cUpgradeError, Msg, FConnection.GetNextMsgID());` so that it's clear that you're looking for the function result instead.

Comment: Or one of the overloads has a similar 3rd argument and the compiler's getting confused - The only way we can help without just guessing is by showing us all the overloaded versions.

Comment: @KenWhite It appears you were correct. Changing to `FConnection.GetNextMsgID()` worked.

Comment: I posted as an answer instead, so people can see that there's a solution. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `FConnection.SendMsg(cUpgradeError, Msg, FConnection.GetNextMsgID);` is trying to interpret `FConnection.GetNextMsgID` as a function pointer instead of a function result.

Change it to `FConnection.SendMsg(cUpgradeError, Msg, FConnection.GetNextMsgID());` so that it's clear that you're looking for the function result instead.